# How to select a command among multiples with priority

Tags: linux, bash, shell, supervisord

I am trying to create a basic utility for which i need `supervisord` installed on machine. But the problem is that its depend on user, how he/she is installing it, so here i am trying to cover almost all scenario to get supervisord command.

Following is my code which i am using right now.

```
if [[ -f "/opt/anaconda/bin/supervisord" ]]; then
  RUNNER="/opt/anaconda/bin/supervisord"
elif [[ -f "/usr/local/bin/supervisord" ]]; then
  RUNNER="/usr/local/bin/supervisord"
elif [[ -f "/usr/bin/supervisord" ]]; then
  RUNNER="/usr/bin/supervisord"
elif [[ "$(command -v supervisord)" ]]; then
  RUNNER="supervisord"
else
  echo "supervisord is not install on this machine"
  exit 1
fi
```

I am looking any better approach to achieve this.

Comment: You should just require the user to configure their `PATH` so it includes the directory with `supervisord`.

Comment: You can use `for` loop to iterate over all possible values and then use `if`/`break` inside.

Comment: @Barmar i am trying to create a solution, for which i don't want to ask to user to configure anything on their end. Just `supervisord` should be installed on their machines.

Comment: @yeputons, Iterate through all paths also kind of same.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: Exploring the solutions or best practices which people follow while creating shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code checks some absolute paths,
and when it finds one that exists,
it will use that.
This is not a good idea.
You can expect users to set their `PATH` in such a way that the correct version of `supervisord` will get used, wherever it is.
In other words, the command available on `PATH` must be the first choice.

```
if type supervisord &>/dev/null; then
  RUNNER=supervisord
elif ...
  ...
fi
```